# Node js Cross-domain session

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, socket.io, chat

Here I will describe the requirement for my project.

Basically I want to build a chat application which I can embed to different websites for example , site build using wordpress, magento, drupal, custom frameworks ... etc . What I actually need is to embed JavaScript for handling socket chat using (socket.io) on some of the website(wordpress, magento, drupal ....), so what I finally have is a set of javascript code (client side), and a server running in nodejs (with socket.io)

The problem I faced is to manage session for registered users after login. Since my code is embedded on different websites and the node server resides on other server , On each page refresh I faced difficult to validate user session session. Could you please help me how I can manage session in a best way for this application.

If you feel difficulty to understand my need , I can explain in detail with examples

Thanking You

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you just need to handle user sessions? More specifically on the client side?

Based on the information you give, I will just assume you either return a unique string representing the session on the server to the client. The format of this can either be a cookie, a normal string/token, etc.

For cookies, you shouldn't have much problems, since the browser deals with this. Although you might need to set it up correctly on the server.

For tokens/strings that needs to be returned to the server for each request requiring authentication, you should store it in the session-storage/local storage of the browser, depending on your need. Then you should embed it in every requests back to the server and authenticate it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question. Since I am sending all the request using socket.emit. Is it possible for me to set session on nodejs server ? More specifically how I can match " string/token" on each side ? (client side and server (nodejs) side) Client side I can do with cookie but on server side how i can save that value ? Which will be a better option (database or session(session not possible for now only socket emit is used to send data accross domains))

Comment: Sessions - this is exactly what they are for. You store the sessions in you memory, which also means a restart of the server requires everyone to log in again.

You can also use a third-party application like Redis to keep track of your stores, especially if your thinking about scaling your server you need to share sessions across server instances.

edit: https://auth0.com/blog/auth-with-socket-io/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable info, Let me try to implement authentication using token